# Visual Studio Extension, Passing objects from VSPackage to IOleCommandTarget

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mef, visual-studio-extensions, languageservice

I have created an object that uses the DTE to access files in a Visual Studio Solution and parse them to extract information to drive new features I am implementing.  This object also uses DTE Events to detect when the contents of the Solution changes.  For this reason the object is scoped in the VSPackage.  However, I need the information the object collects inside a IOleCommandTarget where the features are implemented.  I have tried looking for a way to pass this object from the VSPackage to the IOleCommandTarget but so far I have come up empty.  I have tried scoping the object in the IOleCommandTarget but this does not work because the DTE events will not trigger due to the scope or Garbage Collection, I think.

Here is my IOleCommandTarget provider:

```
internal class VerilogCommandAndControlHandlerProvider : IVsTextViewCreationListener
{
    [Import]
    internal IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService AdapterService = null;
    [Import]
    internal ICompletionBroker CompletionBroker { get; set; }
    [Import]
    internal SVsServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public void VsTextViewCreated(IVsTextView textViewAdapter)
    {
        ITextView textView = AdapterService.GetWpfTextView(textViewAdapter);
        if (textView == null)
            return;

        DTE dte = ((DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)));

        Func<VerilogCommandAndControlHandler> createCommandHandler = delegate () { return new VerilogCommandAndControlHandler(textViewAdapter, textView, dte, this); };
        textView.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty(createCommandHandler);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you not pass this helper class that detects solution changes and collection information to the IOleCommandTarget implementation via constructor argument?

Comment: Sure, the piece I am missing is how to access this helper class inside the IOleCommandTarget provider to pass it in the constructor.

Comment: Regarding the garbage collection problem of DTE events, I normally have a reference to the corresponding events object (e.g BuildEvents, SolutionEvents) stored in a private field in package class. That way, those events objects don't get collected by the GC.

Comment: Looks like you are using MEF, may be you could `Export` your helper class and `Import` it in `VerilogCommandAndControlHandlerProvider` class.